# How to float 3 LI's to the left and 3 to the right and maintain original sequence?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of 6 list items. Each item's width is only 5% of the total UL.
I'm trying to get the remaining 60% of empty space to appear after item 3.

I've attempted by floating items 4,5 & 6 to the right. But that causes them to appear out of sequence. They appear backwards as 6,5 & 4.

How i can achieve the desired results? This is a simplified version. Setting item 3 as width 65% is not an option!

Goal:
1,2,3 60% empty space 4,5,6

```
<ul>
<li class="a">1</li>
<li class="a">2</li>
<li class="a">3</li>

<li class="b">4</li>
<li class="b">5</li>
<li class="b">6</li>
</ul>
```

As stated the below CSS does not work

```
ul#six-items {
list-style-type:none;
width:100%;
}   

li {
width:5%;
}   

li.a {float:left}

li.b {float:right}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="a">1</li>
    <li class="a">2</li>
    <li class="a">3</li>
    <li class="b b4">4</li>
    <li class="b">5</li>
    <li class="b">6</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}   

li { width: 5%; }   

li.b4 { margin-left: auto; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/y8y2edb6/

Answer (score 2):

Using `float`...you can't.

You could split the menu into two separate menus and float them independently (one left and the other right)..or you could use `flexbox`

```css
ul {
list-style-type:none;
  display: flex;
}   

li {
width:5%;
  border:1px solid green;
} 

li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="a">1</li>
<li class="a">2</li>
<li class="a">3</li>

<li class="b">4</li>
<li class="b">5</li>
<li class="b">6</li>
</ul>
```